# Using an R Markdown style document (.Rmd) as input for Pweave

Tags: python, markdown, r-markdown, pweave

I'm trying to run a basic R Markdown document (that calls python in code chunks) through `Pweave`. In the [`Pweave` documentation](http://mpastell.com/pweave/usage.html#markdown) it states that you can declare code chunks using the style ```` ```{python} ````. However when I try to compile using, for example, `pweave -f pandoc FIR_design.mdw` the chunks are not run and instead placed in verbatim.

All the [examples in the documentation](http://mpastell.com/pweave/examples/index.html) use the `noweb` syntax e.g.

```
<<fig = True, width = '12 cm', echo = False>>=
from pylab import *
plot(arange(10))
show()
@
```

The markdown equivalent would be:

````
```{python, fig = True, width = '12 cm', echo = False}
from pylab import *
plot(arange(10))
show()
```
````

When I try to run the examples using the markdown syntax it simply adds them in verbatim and doesn't run the chunk. Is this expected? If so, how should I be converting my `.Rmd` documents to make them runable in `Pweave`. Must I convert them to `noweb` style?

Here is the documentation example document [FIR_design.mdw](http://mpastell.com/pweave/_downloads/FIR_design.mdw) rewritten in .Rmd format (for examples):

- [FIR_design.Rmd](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gfgffks3wlb8z7r/FIR_design.Rmd?dl=0)

Comment: Does the `noweb` style work?

Comment: It does yes. The example .mdw [here](http://mpastell.com/pweave/_downloads/FIR_design.mdw) runs fine with `pweave -f pandoc FIR_design.mdw`. I've made an edit to the below solution which solves the problem. Given an `.Rmd` file, use `pweave -i markdown <source>.Rmd`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `pweave -f pandoc <source>` try using `pweave -i markdown <source>`.

If you do not provide the input format, it is [deduced from file extension](https://github.com/mpastell/Pweave/blob/45b56ec60c5badb4e40796178397a4eae5bdddcb/pweave/pweb.py#L132-L156). As you can see in linked source, your input file needs to have the `.md` extension for it to be auto-detected as "Pandoc markdown" formatted.

The default output format seems to be the same as input, or as provided with `--format (-f)`.